# KSQL Table timestamp for one of table is not populating as intended

Tags: timestamp, ksqldb, ktable

I am building a ktable like below with timestamp as one of the column in the underlying stream. But after creation rowtime is not populating with timestamp column value.

````
CREATE TABLE MTL_PARAMETERS_TT WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='MTL_PARAMETERS_TT', KEY_FORMAT='avro', PARTITIONS=5, REPLICAS=3, timestamp = 'CREATION_DATE', VALUE_FORMAT='avro') AS SELECT
  CAST(MTL_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION_ID AS INTEGER) ORGANIZATION_ID,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(MTL_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION_CODE) ORGANIZATION_CODE,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(MTL_PARAMETERS.CREATION_DATE) CREATION_DATE
FROM MTL_PARAMETERS MTL_PARAMETERS
GROUP BY CAST(MTL_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION_ID AS INTEGER)
EMIT CHANGES;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Most probably column from the source MTL_PARAMETERS.CREATION_DATE does not meet default ksqlDB timestamp format.

To check right ksqlDB timestamp format you can try

select FROM_UNIXTIME(rowtime)

on any stream or table.